# How can i open more than 1000 files using openfiledialog? Or is there any method i can use?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a small program in which user will select set of file (mostly `.CSV`) files and my program will search through them and find required data.

It's working for up to 300 files, but after that its not working. It's giving me an error:

```
InvalidOperationExceprion was Unhandaled
Too Many files are selected. Select Fewer files and try again.
```

What should i do?

Comment: Ask the user to put the files into a directory. Make your program handle directory selection.

Comment: Could you include some code and indicate where this exception is occurring?

Comment: Are you sure that the VB6 tag is appropriate? Also, which version are you using. The [framework 1.1 version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect(v=vs.71).aspx) contained a hard coded limit of 200 files. But even 2.0 doesn't mention that limit.

Comment: @Thilo . Thanx i will try to do that

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am using Microsoft virtual studio 2008 , and .net framework is 4 . And the numbers which i mention that much files ware accepted by program

Comment: Just a note: there's never a space **before** punctuation character, sentence always starts with an uppercase character and if a sentence consists of more parts, they're separated by a comma.

Comment: Try to get the complete string size in your dialog box: You will find that there is a limit 8, 16, 32 or 64 Kilobytes for that string (Don´t know, but a guess as we all know how M$ programmers think - remember the 640KB)

Comment: As @Mort said, show the code.  I was just able to successfully get 12,293 file names using OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() and got no such exception.

Comment: Can you close the files after you search them and before moving on to the next one?

Answer (score 0):

Like Eric Walker said, open file dialog works with 1,000's and 1,000's of files, there is no reason why it would stop at 300.

The best way to loop though files/folders to get info is to use the .GetFiles() method

```
    Dim OFD As New FolderBrowserDialog

    If OFD.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(OFD.SelectedPath)
            If Path.GetExtension(f) = ".txt" Path.GetExtension(f) = ".csv" Then
                Dim reader As String() = File.ReadAllLines(f)
                For each line as String in reader
                      DoSomethingAwesome(line)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

This will cycle through every file in a certain Directory.

Now if you would like to cycle through every file in a file dialog, then you would use this.

```
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog()
    OFD.Multiselect = True

    If OFD.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each f In OFD.FileNames
            If Path.GetExtension(f) = ".txt" Path.GetExtension(f) = ".csv" Then
            Dim reader As String() = File.ReadAllLines(f)
                For Each line As String In reader
                    DoSomethingAwesome(line)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Give one of these a try depending on your preference.

*As a side note, for future posts - please post your attempted code or more details on what you are trying to accomplish and where you are having trouble. Frankly, Im surprised you weren't downvoted (very surprised, people on SO can be ruthless). Just a friendly tip.*